# How to achieve multiple http requests with csv file in jmeter?

Tags: java, csv, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to simulate a user with 2 http request and 1 http request multiple times via csv file. Below is my structure

```
Test Plan
- Thread Group *[No. of threads = 2, Ramp-up = 1, Loop count = 1]*
- - View Results Tree
- - Simple Controller
- - - http request 1
- - - http request 2
- - - while controller *[condition = ${no} (variable from csv file)]*
- - - - http request 3
- - - - CSV Data set Config *[Recycle on EOF = False, Stop on EOF = False, Sharing Mode = All threads] and CSV file has 3 records*
```

Expected: 1 user should execute

> http request 1, http request 2, http request 3, http request 3, http request 3 (since csv has 3 records)

- If i keep **Recycle on EOF = False, Stop on EOF = False** it keeps on running the request until script ends and after end of data (ie 3 rows) it starts throwing error
- If i keep **Recycle on EOF = True, Stop on EOF = True** it runs for only 1 user and stops.
- If i keep **Recycle on EOF = True, Stop on EOF = False** it keeps on running the request until script ends
- If i keep **Recycle on EOF = False, Stop on EOF = True** it runs for only 1 user and stops.

But can't simulate as per my expectation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was possible to achieve your objective

> http request 1, http request 2, http request 3, http request 3, http
>   request 3 (since csv has 3 records)

With following configuration in the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

[image]

Following condition was set in the While controller.

```
${__jexl3("${UNAME}"!="<EOF>")}
```

Where UNAME is a column name

Since the condition is executed in while controller additional condition check was necessary before executing the http request 3

[image]

Please see the structure of the control in the following.
[image]

Hope this is useful

Also it is possible repeat the test with several iterations with following modifications. Added a JSR223 Sampler for resetting the variable and add text EOF to the end of the CSV file.

[image]

Sample [JMeter test](https://github.com/pragmatictesters/JMeter/tree/master/stackoverflow/answers/59683724) plan and [CSV file](https://github.com/pragmatictesters/JMeter/tree/master/stackoverflow/answers/59683724) are available in the GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

1. Amend your [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter/) condition to look like:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${myVar}" != "<EOF>",)}
   ```

   [image]
2. Put your CSV Data Set Config as a child of the While Controller and configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. Add [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) after the CSV Data Set Config and use the same [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as the condition:

   [image]
4. Put your Sampler as a child of the If Controller
5. That's it, you should be able to run your script and get the number of executions equal to the number of lines in the CSV file:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T and Janesh Kodikara... This worked..thanks a lot (y)

Comment: Hey @Dmitri T its not running for multiple threads. I have increased the thread count to 2 but it was executed only once. Any suggestions?